# Scala: Serializing/deserializing a few elements of a class

Tags: scala, serialization

Consider the following toy class:

```
class myGiantClass(){ 
    val serializableElement = ...  
    // lots of other variables and methods here 
}

// main program 
val listOfGiantObjects: List[myGiantClass] = ....
```

What I need is to serialize/deserialize `listOfGiantObjects`. The issue is that `myGiantClass` contains lots of junk objects and variables which I don't/can't serialize/deserialize. Instead the only element of the  `myGiantClass` that I want to serialize is `serializableElement` inside each object of `listOfGiantObjects`. 
So after deserialize, `listOfGiantObjects` is expected to contain a bunch of `myGiantClass` objects which contain only `serializableElement` (the rest set to default).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not define 2-way transformation like [`Iso`](http://julien-truffaut.github.io/Monocle//tut/iso.html)?

Comment: Also it would be nice to specify what serialization method are you using. ***pickle*** for example could refer to at least [pickling](https://github.com/scala/pickling), [upickle](https://github.com/lihaoyi/upickle-pprint) or [picopickle](https://github.com/netvl/picopickle)

Comment: @Odomontois Iso was good suggestion (and potentially an answer). I don't have any specific serialization in my mind. I will change it to "serialization" to keep it general.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are two approaches (or defaults): **all** elements should be serialized by default, or **none**.

Within the "all" scenario, you could take a look at the **@transient** annotation, for marking fields that should *not* be serialized.

It may seem an unoptimal approach in case of a large number of elements that should not be serialized. However, it **does** communicate what you are trying to achieve. Moreover, you could arrange your code using composition or inner classes to better define the scope of serialization.

At last resort, ad-hoc serializaion with custom attributes is a way (e.g., to implement the *none-by-default* scenario).